Loop over grouped data in R
I have two dataframes, one where id is a primary identifier and the other is long data. I merged both and so I have long data (this can be reversed). I grouped the data based on id and want to loop over each group, generating a new variable value for each row in a group based on some condition. For instance, I want to loop over each group and for every row in a group, if any sdx is True, my new_variable = difftime between current date and preceding date and 0 if it is the first on row in the group.
Please see sample data below:
data.frame(structure(
  list(id = c("0000", 
              "0000", "0000", 
              "0001", "0001", 
              "0001", "0002", 
              "0002", "0002", 
              "0002"),  
       sex = c("F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F"), 
       age_fcat = structure(c(5L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
                              4L), levels = c("18-34", "35-44", "45-54", "54-64", "65+"
                              ), class = "factor"), 
       avg_s = c(161, 
                 161, 155.666666666667, 146, 140, 144, 139, 173, 152.875, 
                 156.5), 
       alx = c(88, 88, 90.3333333333333, 76, 78, 
               73, 86, 97, 82, 97.2), 
       date = seq(as.Date("1990/1/1"), as.Date("1999/1/1"), "years"),
       sdx = c(TRUE, 
               TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE)
  )))


Expected outcome


There's no need to loop.  This is what dplyr::group_by (and many other options) is designed for.  df <- df %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(new_variable = alx > 80).

Also, there is no need for grouping if a new value should be created for each row independent of the group. All you need is dat$new_variable = +dat$alx > 80L, where dat is your data.

@Limey your suggestion will produce one row for each group (as much as I know) and that's not what I want. I want one variable for each row

Does this answer your question? Using group_by and mutate in dplyr package to create new factor variable by id variable

@Friede the condition depends on the values in other rows of a group, so I need a function that loops through a group independent of the other entries in the data

No, you say "For instance, I want to loop over the group with id = '0000' and for each row in that group, if alx is greater than 80, my new_variable = True". Then provide different (non single-grouped) data.

The most direct way to solve this problem is to provide a simple and reproducible example dataset along with the expected outcome.

@Limey it doesn't answer my question.

"@Limey your suggestion will produce one row for each group (as much as I know) and that's not what I want. I want one variable for each row".  That is incorrect.  I use mutate, not summarise.  (Did you even try my code before commenting?)  "@Limey it doesn't answer my question.":  I think you mean "In my opinion, it doesn't answer my question"....  You appear to be in a minority.  By the way, your sample code does not generate a data.frame.  It creates a list that does not conform to your description.  You may find the reprex package helpful.

thanks @Friede, edited my question.  I'm trying to express it the best way I can. It's a bit convoluted and I am not an advanced R user

@Limey I mean no offense and I appreciate you suggestion. I tried your code and yes it works, I was wrong. it however doesn't check other values in the group like I want it to. It's all my fault I didn't express the problem clearly enough. I've edited the question

provide data with more than one group.

For groups that don't meet the specified condition (no sdx is true), I'd use a default value (NA in the example above)
